# What kind of led would be used for this keyboard

Tags: led, keyboard

I have a project that involves [this keyboard](https://www.1upkeyboards.com/shop/keyboard-kits/zlant-40-keyboard-kit/), it has 12 sections on the pcb marked UX (X being 1-12) for what I guess are for leds. If I'm correct what kind of led would I buy for it? Something like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1655)?

Edit: 
Here's a picture [image: closeup picture of zlant led]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I suggest that you make it easy for your readers by adding the photo into your question. That way the question will still be relevant if the link dies.

Comment: Can you measure the footprint size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The pads are for *WS2812B* leds. (SK6812 will also work) ([ws2812b datasheet](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/108))
- The leds (NeoPixel) in the [link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1655) you have shared will work with the PCB you have.
- Also, just take a quick look at [this](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=96089.0) forum. There the people suggest that if you use the plate that comes with the kit, the leds won't shine through much. You will be better off using some translucent acrylic plates.
- You should test the polarity on the pads and align the leds with the help of following pin diagram. Also, just check if you are getting 5v on the pads before soldering on the leds.

[image: Pin out diagram for WS2812B/SK6812]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also messaged the maker of the pcb and he said to use the ws2812b led’s as well. The led’s will be under a set of keycaps and encased in an acrylic case so I think I should be fine with the shine. Also taking a look at the default qmk page it looks like I can directly change the led brightness with two keys.